# Detecting the edges of an image with a similar colored background

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to use openCV and python to extract the details of the image and then store it in a csv.
Since it would be increase the accuracy of OCR to retrieve the data from the text, i am trying to pre-process the image and generate a bird-eye view.
The image has a lot of noise and the background is similar to the the color of the region of interest.

### Source image

[image]

**Approach 1)** 
I used gaussian blurring followed by adaptive thresholding to get rid of some noise.
Followed by morphological transformations to get a fair binary image.
Then i searched for the contours in this area usingf the external hierarchy and then sorted according to the area.
Also the contours that are produced on the card edges are open and hence sorting by area isnt working like i expected it to.
But I couldn't come up with the desired output.

```
def pre_process_image(img, skip_dilate=False):

  proc = cv2.GaussianBlur(img.copy(), (9, 9), 0)
  # ret, proc = cv2.threshold(proc,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
  # edged = cv2.Canny(proc, 100, 200)
  proc = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(proc, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

  if not skip_dilate:
    kernel = np.array([[0., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 1.], [1., 1., 0.]], np.uint8)
    proc = cv2.dilate(proc, kernel)
  # proc = cv2.erode(proc.copy(), cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5)), iterations = 1)  
  return proc

processed = pre_process_image(res.copy())
contours = cv2.findContours(processed.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)  # Find contours
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)
contours = sorted(contours, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)

max_len = 0
for cnt in contours:
  if(cv2.arcLength(cnt, False) > max_len):
    max_len = cv2.arcLength(cnt, False)
    connt = cnt


p = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
external_only = cv2.drawContours(p.copy(), connt, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

[image: LOL epic Fail]

**Approach 2)** HoughTransform to detect the edges after basic preprocessing

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (9, 9), 0) 

# res = cv2.equalizeHist(blur)
# res2 = np.hstack((gray, tut))

# # Apply edge detection method on the image 
edges = cv2.Canny(blur,50,150,apertureSize = 3) 

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180, 50) 

for r,theta in lines[0]: 

   a = np.cos(theta) 
   b = np.sin(theta) 

   x0 = a*r 
   y0 = b*r 
   x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b)) 
   y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a)) 
   x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b)) 
   y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a)) 

   cv2.line(img,(x1,y1), (x2,y2), (0,0,255),4)
```

[image: lol fail]

It be very helpful if someone could point out my mistakes and sujjest a much more efficient way to achieve good results.I am a beginner to image processing so might not be aware about most theory but a good diretion to work forward would be much appreciated.
TIA!

Answer (score 0):

May be use preprocessing image (delete color elements):

```
import cv2 as cv
low_H = 0
low_S = 50
low_V = 0
high_H = 255
high_S = 255
high_V = 255
frame = cv.imread('IE.jpg')
frame_HSV = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
frame_threshold = cv.inRange(frame_HSV, (low_H, low_S, low_V), (high_H, high_S, high_V))
blank=cv.cvtColor(frame_threshold, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR) 
out=cv.bitwise_or(frame, blank)
out=cv.cvtColor(out, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv.imwrite('out_card.png', out)
```

[image]